# Converting Location to sexagesimal in Android?

Tags: android, location

Is there a way to get coordinates from a Location object in sexagesimal form (N 42° 30' 15.130'') ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(untested)

```
  double lon = Double.parseDouble(latlon[0]); // contains lon string
  double lat = Double.parseDouble(latlon[1]);
  String ew = "";      String ns = "";

  if(lon < 0)
      ew = "W";
  else 
      ew = "E";

  if(lat < 0)
     ns = "S";
  else 
     ns = "N";

  String latitude, longitude;      
  int d = (int)lon;
  longitude = ew + " " + d + "°";       
  double mm = (lon - d) * 60;
  int m = (int)mm;
  String minutes = new Double(m).toString();  
  double ss = (mm - m)*60;
  String secs =  new Double(ss).toString();
  longitude += minutes + "'" + secs + "\"";
```

Do the same for latitude.